# SCP. Error: Information [4]: Select a raster, raster not loaded

Tags: qgis, raster, scp, cartographic-information-model

I have problem with the complement of SCP. I try to classified but in the moment to select the training input it doesn´t work. It showed me this message:

> Information [4]: Select a raster, raster not loaded.

I can´t understand please help me with this.